# How do I extract results coming from sql in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js

I am fairly new to SQL using with nodejs ,I am using **knex** raw to run sql queries,I am trying to add two column

this is my code

```
db.raw("SELECT SUM(`column1`) + SUM(`column2`) FROM `sales` AS `total`")
 .then(result => console.log(result[0]))
```

if I am running this I am getting this in console

```
 [RowDataPacket {
    'SUM(`column1`) + SUM(`column2`)': 33458338.169500016 } ]
```

I was expecting to get

```
 [RowDataPacket {
    'total': 33458338.169500016 } ]
```

But,since it doesn't matter what it name,I only want number so I tried this

```
db.raw("SELECT SUM(`column1`) + SUM(`column2`) FROM `sales` AS `total`")
 .then(result => console.log(result[0]['SUM(`column1`) + SUM(`column2`)']))
```

I am getting **`undefined`** in console

How do I get the total number ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SELECT SUM(`column1`) + SUM(`column2`) AS `total` FROM `sales`
```

this will solve your first part and since your output of `result[0]` still shows an array, you might consider using `result[0][0].total`

Comment: updated the answer, seems from your data, `result[0]` is an array

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
db.('sales').sum({ total: ['column1', 'column2'] })
```

Comment: something like this "knex('users').sum({ sum: ['products', 'orders'] }) ",                          I tried "db('sales').sum({ total: ['column1', 'column2'] })" but that is also giving SQL syntax error

Comment: What is your table structure and what is the error?